# Show full file name using render in grails

Tags: grails

`render` in grails does not showing full file name with spaces while downloading file in browser. The file name is showing a word up to the first space in file name.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Is the issue that the file will not download or that the name is changed once the file is downloaded making it hard for the user to find the file? Dealing with spaces is problematic and swapping the space character for a hyphen or underscore will alleviate many file name issues.